# How to give secondary theme color to DatePicker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, datepicker

I am new to material UI and I was playing around with components but I got stuck in an issue.

```html
<TextField type="email" name="email" id="email" label="Email" variant="outlined" color="secondary" required />

<DatePicker label="Basic date picker" />
```

Just like how I gave a color prop and variant prop to the TextField component, I want to give DatePicker the same props but the typescript gives me an error saying color doesn't exist on this type. I opened the documentation. I found a slots prop but it didn't help either. I can apply color via CSS but I wanna do things the right way. Using CSS will be redundant. Any idea how I cant solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out about the `slotProps` prop in the `DatePicker` and this fixed my problem. We can provide props to any element used in the `DatePicker` component. Check out the `slotProps` prop of [MUI DatePicker](https://mui.com/x/api/date-pickers/date-picker/#props)

```html
<DatePicker
  label="Joining date"
  slotProps={{
    textField: {
      name: "joiningDate",
      id: "joiningDate",
      color: "secondary",
      required: true
    }
  }}
/>
```